# jquery getting id and appending .html & toggleClass

Tags: jquery, load, find, append

Im new to jquery and would be happy to get some tipps on this. I have a couple of links and I want to load their content to my #content div. I don't use a href so I want to load the id and append .html (example: the first link got id="link1". On click I want to load link1.html to the #content div.). Additionally, I want to toggle the class of the clicked link from inactive to active and find the previous active link and change that one to inactive.

So this is what I tried:

```
$(".link").click(function() {
    var linkHref = $(this).attr("id");
    var loadHref = linkHref.append(linkHref + ".html");
    $("#content").load(loadHref);
    $("#nav").find(".active").toggleClass("active inactive");
    $(this).children("a").toggleClass("inactive active");
});
```

The HTML:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#" id="link1" class="active link">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="link2" class="inactive link">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="link3" class="inactive link">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Output: nothing happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`append` is a method of jQuery object and `attr` returns a string(a String object) that doesn't have `append` method,  if you want to concatenate strings you should use `+` operator instead. Also note that you have bound the handler to the `a` elements not the `li` elements and there is no need to use `children`.

```
var linkHref = $(this).attr("id") + '.html';
```

```
$(".link").click(function(e) {
    // Prevent the default action of the event
    e.preventDefault();
    var linkHref = this.id + '.html';
    $("#content").load(linkHref);
    $("#nav a.active").toggleClass('inactive active');
    $(this).addClass("active").removeClass('inactive');
});
```

Comment: Ah I see, things are getting clearer right now. Thank you very much! One last thing: the e.preventDefault(); forces the browser to not navigate to the url in the a tag, right? Thats what I thought I got the href="#" for. If I wouldnt have this, I would have like href="link1.html" and could load that in my content. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @user2179266 You are welcome, yes, if you use `preventDefault` method then you can use `href` property instead of ID.